# Can't get json with axios.get and headers

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, axios

I am trying to get the joke from https://icanhazdadjoke.com/. This is the code I used

```
const getDadJoke = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get('https://icanhazdadjoke.com/', {headers: {Accept: 'application/json'}})
    console.log(res.data.joke)
}

getDadJoke()
```

I expected to get the joke but instead I got the full html page, as if I didn't specify the headers at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the API documentation for icanhazdadjoke.com, there is a section titled "[Custom user agent](https://icanhazdadjoke.com/api#custom-user-agent)." In that section, they explain how they want any requests to have a User Agent header. If you use Axios in a browser context, the User Agent is set for you by your browser. But I'm going to go out on a limb and say that you are running this code via Node, in which case, you may manually need to set the User Agent header, like so:

```
const getDadJoke = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(
        'https://icanhazdadjoke.com/',
        {
            headers:
            {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'User-Agent': 'my URL, email or whatever'
            }
        }
    )
    console.log(res.data.joke)
}

getDadJoke()
```

The docs say what they want you to put for the User Agent, but I think it would honestly work if there were any User Agent field at all.

Comment: Ohh I am using node, thank you that worked.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please accept the answer so that other users can get clear idea of correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML page you're getting is a 503 response from Cloudflare.

As per the [API documentation](https://icanhazdadjoke.com/api#custom-user-agent)

> #### Custom user agent
>
> If you intend on using the *icanhazdadjoke.com* API we kindly ask that you set a custom `User-Agent` header for all requests.

My guess is they have a [Cloudflare Browser Integrity Check](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170086-Understanding-the-Cloudflare-Browser-Integrity-Check) configured that's triggering for the default Node / Axios user-agent.

Setting a custom user-agent appears to get around this...

```js
const getDadJoke = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get("https://icanhazdadjoke.com/", {
      headers: {
        accept: "application/json",
        "user-agent": "My Node and Axios app", // use something better than this
      },
    });
    console.log(res.data.joke);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.response?.data, err.toJSON());
  }
};
```

---

Given how unreliable Axios releases have been since v1.0.0, I highly recommend you switch to something else. The Fetch API is available natively in Node since v18

```js
const getDadJoke = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch("https://icanhazdadjoke.com/", {
      headers: {
        accept: "application/json",
        "user-agent": "My Node and Fetch app", // use something better than this
      },
    });

    if (!res.ok) {
      const err = new Error(`${res.status} ${res.statusText}`);
      err.text = await res.text();
      throw err;
    }
    console.log((await res.json()).joke);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err, err.text);
  }
};
```